# Why am I getting mismatched input?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to fix mistakes in this source code, I'm still pretty new, but I think there all easy fixes, I was able to sort some of it out, and currently stuck at line 12, saying Mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting '='. Any help is appreciated. It's suppose to be similar to market cipher except the divergence part.

TIA

```
// FUNCTIONS {
// WaveTrend
f_wavetrend(_src, _chlen, _avg, _malen) => _esa = ema(_src, _chlen) 
_de = ema(abs(_src - _esa), _chlen) 
_ci = (_src - _esa) / (0.015 * _de) 
_tci = ema(_ci, _avg) 
_wt1 = _tci 
_wt2 = sma(_wt1, _malen), [_wt1, _wt2]  *** currently stuck here

// 8 EMA Ribbon 
f_emaRibbon(_src, _e1, _e2, _e3, _e4, _e5, _e6, _e7, _e8) => _ema1 = ema(_src, _e1)
_ema2 = ema(_src, _e2) 
_ema3 = ema(_src, _e3) 
_ema4 = ema(_src, _e4) 
_ema5 = ema(_src, _e5) 
_ema6 = ema(_src, _e6)
_ema7 = ema(_src, _e7) 
_ema8 = ema(_src, _e8) [_ema1, _ema2, _ema3, _ema4, _ema5, _ema6, _ema7, _ema8]

f_rsimfi(_period, _multiplier, _tf) => security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf, sma(((close - open) / (high - 
low)) * _multiplier, _period))

// } FUNCTIONS

// PARAMETERS {

// WaveTrend 
wtChannelLen = input(9, title = 'WT Channel Length') 
wtAverageLen = input(13, title = 'WT Average Length') 
wtMASource = input(hlc3, title = 'WT MA Source') 
wtMALen = input(3, title = 'WT MA Length')

// WaveTrend Overbought & Oversold lines 
obLevel = input(53, title = 'WT Overbought Level 1') 
obLevel2 = input(60, title = 'WT Overbought Level 2') 
obLevel3 = input(100, title = 'WT Overbought Level 3') 
osLevel = input(-53, title = 'WT Oversold Level 1') 
osLevel2 = input(-60, title = 'WT Oversold Level 2') 
osLevel3 = input(-80, title = 'WT Oversold Level 3')

// EMA 
Ribbon showRibbon = input(true, "Show Ribbon") 
ema1Len = input(5, title = "EMA 1 Length") 
ema2Len = input(11, title = "EMA 2 Length") 
ema3Len = input(15, title = "EMA 3 Length") 
ema4Len = input(18, title = "EMA 4 Length") 
ema5Len = input(21, title = "EMA 5 Length") 
ema6Len = input(24, title = "EMA 6 Length") 
ema7Len = input(28, title = "EMA 7 Length") 
ema8Len = input(34, title = "EMA 8 Length")

// RSI 
rsiSRC = input(close, title = "RSI Source")
rsiLen = input(14, title = "RSI Length") 
rsiOversold = input(30, title = 'RSI Oversold', minval = 50, maxval = 100) 
rsiOverbought = input(60, title = 'RSI Overbought', minval = 0, maxval = 50)

// RSI+MFI
rsiMFIShow = input(true, title = "Show RSI+MFI") 
rsiMFIperiod = input(60, title = 'RSI+MFI Period') 
rsiMFIMultiplier = input(150, title = 'RSI+MFI Area multiplier')

// }

// CALCULATE INDICATORS {

// EMA Ribbon 
[ema1, ema2, ema3, ema4, ema5, ema6, ema7, ema8] = f_emaRibbon(close, ema1Len, ema2Len, ema3Len, 
ema4Len, ema5Len, ema6Len, ema7Len, ema8Len)

// RSI 
rsi = rsi(rsiSRC, rsiLen)

// Calculates WaveTrend 
[wt1, wt2] = f_wavetrend(wtMASource, wtChannelLen, wtAverageLen, wtMALen)

// WaveTrend Conditions 
wtOverSold = wt2 <= osLevel wtOverBought = wt2 >= obLevel wtCross = cross(wt1, wt2) 
wtCrossUp = wt2 - wt1 <= 0 wtCrossDown = wt2 - wt1 >= 0

// RSI + MFI 
rsiMFI = f_rsimfi(rsiMFIperiod, rsiMFIMultiplier, timeframe.period)

// Signals 
longEma = crossover(ema2, ema8) 
redCross = crossunder(ema1, ema2)
blueTriangle = crossover(ema2, ema3) 
redDiamond = wtCross and wtCrossDown 
yellowCross = redDiamond and wt2 < 45 and wt2 > osLevel3 and rsi < 30 and rsi > 15 and rsiMFI < -5 
bloodDiamond = redDiamond and redCross bullCandle = open > ema2 and open > ema8 and (close[1] > 
open[1]) and (close > open) and not redDiamond and not redCross 
shortEma = crossover(ema8, ema2)

// } CALCULATE INDICATORS

// DRAW {

// EMA Ribbon 
ribbonDir = ema8 < ema2 colorEma = ribbonDir ? color.green : color.red 
p1 = plot(ema1, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #1573d4 : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, 
title="EMA 1") 
p2 = plot(ema2, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #3096ff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, 
title="EMA 2") 
plot(ema3, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #57abff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, 
title="EMA 3") 
plot(ema4, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #85c2ff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, 
title="EMA 4") 
plot(ema5, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #9bcdff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, 
title="EMA 5") 
plot(ema6, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #b3d9ff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, 
title="EMA 6") 
plot(ema7, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #c9e5ff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, 
title="EMA 7") 
plot(ema8, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #dfecfb : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, 
title="EMA 8") 
p8 = plot(ema8, color=showRibbon ? na : colorEma, linewidth=2, transp=0, title="EMA 8") 
fill(p1, p2, color = #1573d4, transp = 85) fill(p2, p8, color = #363a45, transp = 85)

// SHAPES

plotshape(longEma, style=shape.circle, color=#00ff00, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, 
title="Long EMA Signal", transp=50) 
plotshape(shortEma, style=shape.circle, color=#ff0000, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, 
title="Short EMA Signal", transp=50) 
plotshape(redCross, style=shape.xcross, color=#ff0000, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, 
title="Red cross", transp=50) 
plotshape(blue_Triangle, style=shape.triangleup, color=#0064ff, location=location.abovebar, 
size=size.small, title="Blue Triangle", transp=50) 
plotshape(redDiamond, style=shape.diamond, color=#ff0000, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, 
title="Red Diamond", transp=25) 
plotshape(bullCandle, style=shape.diamond, color=color.yellow, location=location.abovebar, 
size=size.tiny, title="Bull candle", transp=75) 
plotshape(bloodDiamond, style=shape.diamond, color=#ff0000, location=location.abovebar, 
size=size.small, title="Blood Diamond", transp=15) 
plotshape(yellowCross, style=shape.xcross, color=color.yellow, location=location.abovebar, 
size=size.small, title="Yellow Cross", transp=25) // } DRAW

// ALERTS{ 
alertcondition(redDiamond != 0, "Red Diamond", "Red Diamond") 
alertcondition(bloodDiamond != 0, "Blood Diamond", "Blood Diamond") 
alertcondition(yellowCross != 0, "YellowX", "YellowX") 
alertcondition(redCross != 0, "RedX", "RedX") 
alertcondition(longEma != 0, "Longema", "Longema") 
alertcondition(blueTriangle != 0, "Bluetriangle", "Bluetriangle") 
// } ALERTS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bad copy-paste job to me.
There were multiple issues with this script (mostly indentation).

This will compile and plot, but you're missing the `blue_Triangle` variable.
I've commented that out in the plot section.

```
//@version=4
study(title="MyScript", overlay=true)

// FUNCTIONS {
// WaveTrend
f_wavetrend(_src, _chlen, _avg, _malen) => 
    _esa = ema(_src, _chlen) 
    _de = ema(abs(_src - _esa), _chlen) 
    _ci = (_src - _esa) / (0.015 * _de) 
    _tci = ema(_ci, _avg) 
    _wt1 = _tci 
    _wt2 = sma(_wt1, _malen)
    [_wt1, _wt2]  //*** currently stuck here

// 8 EMA Ribbon 
f_emaRibbon(_src, _e1, _e2, _e3, _e4, _e5, _e6, _e7, _e8) => 
    _ema1 = ema(_src, _e1)
    _ema2 = ema(_src, _e2) 
    _ema3 = ema(_src, _e3) 
    _ema4 = ema(_src, _e4) 
    _ema5 = ema(_src, _e5) 
    _ema6 = ema(_src, _e6)
    _ema7 = ema(_src, _e7) 
    _ema8 = ema(_src, _e8) 
    [_ema1, _ema2, _ema3, _ema4, _ema5, _ema6, _ema7, _ema8]

f_rsimfi(_period, _multiplier, _tf) => security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf, sma(((close - open) / (high - low)) * _multiplier, _period))

// } FUNCTIONS

// PARAMETERS {

// WaveTrend 
wtChannelLen = input(9, title = 'WT Channel Length') 
wtAverageLen = input(13, title = 'WT Average Length') 
wtMASource = input(hlc3, title = 'WT MA Source') 
wtMALen = input(3, title = 'WT MA Length')

// WaveTrend Overbought & Oversold lines 
obLevel = input(53, title = 'WT Overbought Level 1') 
obLevel2 = input(60, title = 'WT Overbought Level 2') 
obLevel3 = input(100, title = 'WT Overbought Level 3') 
osLevel = input(-53, title = 'WT Oversold Level 1') 
osLevel2 = input(-60, title = 'WT Oversold Level 2') 
osLevel3 = input(-80, title = 'WT Oversold Level 3')

// EMA 
//Ribbon 
showRibbon = input(true, "Show Ribbon") 
ema1Len = input(5, title = "EMA 1 Length") 
ema2Len = input(11, title = "EMA 2 Length") 
ema3Len = input(15, title = "EMA 3 Length") 
ema4Len = input(18, title = "EMA 4 Length") 
ema5Len = input(21, title = "EMA 5 Length") 
ema6Len = input(24, title = "EMA 6 Length") 
ema7Len = input(28, title = "EMA 7 Length") 
ema8Len = input(34, title = "EMA 8 Length")

// RSI 
rsiSRC = input(close, title = "RSI Source")
rsiLen = input(14, title = "RSI Length") 
rsiOversold = input(30, title = 'RSI Oversold', minval = 50, maxval = 100) 
rsiOverbought = input(60, title = 'RSI Overbought', minval = 0, maxval = 50)

// RSI+MFI
rsiMFIShow = input(true, title = "Show RSI+MFI") 
rsiMFIperiod = input(60, title = 'RSI+MFI Period') 
rsiMFIMultiplier = input(150, title = 'RSI+MFI Area multiplier')

// }

// CALCULATE INDICATORS {

// EMA Ribbon 
[ema1, ema2, ema3, ema4, ema5, ema6, ema7, ema8] = f_emaRibbon(close, ema1Len, ema2Len, ema3Len, ema4Len, ema5Len, ema6Len, ema7Len, ema8Len)

// RSI 
rsi = rsi(rsiSRC, rsiLen)

// Calculates WaveTrend 
[wt1, wt2] = f_wavetrend(wtMASource, wtChannelLen, wtAverageLen, wtMALen)

// WaveTrend Conditions 
wtOverSold = wt2 <= osLevel 
wtOverBought = wt2 >= obLevel 
wtCross = cross(wt1, wt2) 
wtCrossUp = wt2 - wt1 <= 0 
wtCrossDown = wt2 - wt1 >= 0

// RSI + MFI 
rsiMFI = f_rsimfi(rsiMFIperiod, rsiMFIMultiplier, timeframe.period)

// Signals 
longEma = crossover(ema2, ema8) 
redCross = crossunder(ema1, ema2)
blueTriangle = crossover(ema2, ema3) 
redDiamond = wtCross and wtCrossDown 
yellowCross = redDiamond and wt2 < 45 and wt2 > osLevel3 and rsi < 30 and rsi > 15 and rsiMFI < -5 
bloodDiamond = redDiamond and redCross 
bullCandle = open > ema2 and open > ema8 and (close[1] > open[1]) and (close > open) and not redDiamond and not redCross 
shortEma = crossover(ema8, ema2)

// } CALCULATE INDICATORS

// DRAW {

// EMA Ribbon 
ribbonDir = ema8 < ema2 
colorEma = ribbonDir ? color.green : color.red 
p1 = plot(ema1, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #1573d4 : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, title="EMA 1") 
p2 = plot(ema2, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #3096ff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, title="EMA 2") 
plot(ema3, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #57abff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, title="EMA 3") 
plot(ema4, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #85c2ff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, title="EMA 4") 
plot(ema5, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #9bcdff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, title="EMA 5") 
plot(ema6, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #b3d9ff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, title="EMA 6") 
plot(ema7, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #c9e5ff : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, title="EMA 7") 
plot(ema8, color=showRibbon ? ribbonDir ? #dfecfb : color.gray : na, linewidth=2, transp=15, title="EMA 8") 
p8 = plot(ema8, color=showRibbon ? na : colorEma, linewidth=2, transp=0, title="EMA 8") 
fill(p1, p2, color = #1573d4, transp = 85) 
fill(p2, p8, color = #363a45, transp = 85)

// SHAPES

plotshape(longEma, style=shape.circle, color=#00ff00, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, title="Long EMA Signal", transp=50) 
plotshape(shortEma, style=shape.circle, color=#ff0000, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, title="Short EMA Signal", transp=50) 
plotshape(redCross, style=shape.xcross, color=#ff0000, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, title="Red cross", transp=50) 
//plotshape(blue_Triangle, style=shape.triangleup, color=#0064ff, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, title="Blue Triangle", transp=50) 
plotshape(redDiamond, style=shape.diamond, color=#ff0000, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, title="Red Diamond", transp=25) 
plotshape(bullCandle, style=shape.diamond, color=color.yellow, location=location.abovebar, size=size.tiny, title="Bull candle", transp=75) 
plotshape(bloodDiamond, style=shape.diamond, color=#ff0000, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, title="Blood Diamond", transp=15) 
plotshape(yellowCross, style=shape.xcross, color=color.yellow, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, title="Yellow Cross", transp=25) 
// } DRAW

// ALERTS{ 
alertcondition(redDiamond != 0, "Red Diamond", "Red Diamond") 
alertcondition(bloodDiamond != 0, "Blood Diamond", "Blood Diamond") 
alertcondition(yellowCross != 0, "YellowX", "YellowX") 
alertcondition(redCross != 0, "RedX", "RedX") 
alertcondition(longEma != 0, "Longema", "Longema") 
alertcondition(blueTriangle != 0, "Bluetriangle", "Bluetriangle") 
// } ALERTS
```